# How to show one hour later from now or one hour before now in ruby

Tags: ruby, time

```
x = Time.now
y = 1.hours.from_now
z = 1.hours.before_now
```

i'm sorry if this question too stupid. i want to know an effective way to show one hour before and after now in ruby.
thanks for watching and for helping.

Comment: For the benefit of readers who are new to Ruby, please show `require`'s when needed (here, `require 'time'`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no such methods in Ruby. You'll have to do:

```
Time.now + 1*60*60 # 1.hours.from_now -> 1 hour, 60 minutes, 60 seconds
Time.now - 1*60*60 # 1.hours.before_now -> 1 hour, 60 minutes, 60 seconds
```

or you can include `activesupport` in your project.

Comment: Can you tell me why 1 multiplied by 60 and 60. why 60 should be twice not just one.

Comment: @WawanSumardi: As I stated in code's comment. for 1 hour you have `1` and then in one hour you have `60` minutes, one minute has `60` seconds. Hence, `1*60*60`, Similarly for 2 hours you have: `2*60*60`

Answer (score 4):

Also you can write in this manner :

**Current Time:**

x = Time.now    `=> 2017-02-14 11:55:17 +0530`

**one hour ago ( one hour before):**

y = x - 1.hour  `=> 2017-02-14 10:55:17 +0530`

or

y = **1.hour.ago**  `=> 2017-02-14 10:55:17 +0530` `# available in rails v4.2

**one hour later/since ( one hour after ):**

z = x + 1.hour  `=> 2017-02-14 12:55:17 +0530`

or

z = **1.hour.since**  `=> 2017-02-14 12:55:17 +0530` `# available in rails v4.2`

Note: this calculation perform on x(stored time) not real time(Time.now) but in case of ago and since calculation perform on real time(Time.now)

Comment: These method available in rails v4.2 and later